# Why does the mouse disappear in DISCL_EXCLUSIVE | DISCL_FOREGROUND mode?

Tags: windows, winapi, directinput

When using DirectInput, why does the mouse cursor completely disappear when you use DISCL_EXCLUSIVE | DISCL_FOREGROUND as your cooperative level?

```
mouse->SetCooperativeLevel ( hwnd, DISCL_EXCLUSIVE | DISCL_FOREGROUND ) ;
```

Even though DirectInput is deprecated, does the very fact the mouse is not even *available* to WINDOWS mean that you're slightly more responsive and better when using DirectInput (vs RAWINPUT)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time I opened this question I didn't realize that `DISCL_EXCLUSIVE | DISCL_FOREGROUND` setting in DirectInput really amounts to `RIDEV_CAPTUREMOUSE | RIDEV_NOLEGACY` for the mouse in RAWINPUT.  You can simply call `ShowCursor( FALSE );` to hide the cursor then.